# Expected ' ' before '=' token in struct definition

Tags: c, struct

I have a `struct` I am making for a case to model a simple semaphore, the code is as follows

```
struct semaphore{
    int count = 1;
    struct PCB *Sem_Queue;
};
```

When I try to compile I get the error

> Expected ':', ',' etc before '=' token int count = 1;

Can anyone point out to me why this error is occurring?

Comment: You can't have initializers in a struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are trying to set a default value for a field in a `struct` definition.

You cannot do this.

You have to declare the `count` field like you did with `PCB`: with only a type and a name, like so:

```
int count;
```

Comment: @chqrlie Oops sorry I'll fix that.

Answer (score 5):

In C, you're not allowed to give initial values to elements in `struct`s. If you'd like to create a `semaphore` struct where every new `semaphore`'s `count` field is set to 1, you can do so by creating a helper function like

```
 struct semaphore* semaphore_new()
```

that returns a newly-allocated `semaphore*` and sets the `count` field before returning it.